# Words pronounced "subtle or gemene messed-up" in Australian English

Tags: listening, australian-english

There’s a short passage that I don’t understand in a formal speech in a youtube video.
The passage starts at 6:30, and the URL is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJJX123tIwA#t=6m25s
Here is my transcript of the passage, with the part that I don’t get in boldface :

> Catholic seminaries were almost emptied.
>   Convents were a smouldering wreck of
>   **subtle or gemene messed-up**
>   nuns, who were the remnants of the vast numbers that used to be there.

The speaker is from Australia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I hear:

> **Countless** seminaries were almost emptied. Convents were a smouldering wreck of **psychologically** messed-up nuns who were the remnants of the vast numbers that used to be there. It was an astonishingly rapid collapse.

As you can see, you actually got two words wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. However, I still think it's "emptied" not "empty" here, I'm sure there's a "d" sound

Comment: I think you're right. I just gave it another listen and it does sound like there is a "d" at the end of **empty**.